# Set a timer for a function

Tags: unix, time, timer, signals, ocaml

I have defined a list of values: `data : int list` and a function `f: int -> unit`, and a piece of code:

```
for i = 0 to (List.length data) - 1 do
  let d = List.nth data i in
  f d
done
```

Now, I would like to set a maximal running time for `f`. For instance, if `f d` exceeds a certain time `maximal`, the execution of `f d` stops, and we carry on with the next element of `data`.

Does anyone know how to do it?

**Update1:**

Following the comments, I would like to add that, the application of `f` to a good part of elements of `data` will end up by raising an exception. This is normal and accepted. So the code looks like:

```
List.iter
  (fun d ->
     try
       (f d)
     with
     | e ->
       printf "%s\n" (Printexc.to_string e))
data
```

Comment: You should write the loop as follows: `List.iter f data`. Your method introduces an unnecessary quadratic complexity. (Not an answer to your timing question, sorry.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is based on Jeffrey's answer, with some modifications to improve exception safety:

```
exception Timeout

let run_with_timeout timeout f x =
  let old_handler = Sys.signal Sys.sigalrm
    (Sys.Signal_handle (fun _ -> raise Timeout)) in
  let finish () =
    ignore (Unix.alarm 0);
    ignore (Sys.signal Sys.sigalrm old_handler) in
  try
    ignore (Unix.alarm timeout);
    ignore (f x);
    finish ()
  with Timeout -> finish ()
   | exn -> finish (); raise exn
```

Comment: And thank you! I'm still not sure what happened to the edit? Oh well.

Answer (score 5):

Something like this might work for you:

```
exception Timeout

let run_with_timeout t f x =
    try
        Sys.set_signal Sys.sigalrm (Sys.Signal_handle (fun _ -> raise Timeout));
        ignore (Unix.alarm t);
        f x;
        ignore (Unix.alarm 0);
        Sys.set_signal Sys.sigalrm Sys.Signal_default
    with Timeout -> Sys.set_signal Sys.sigalrm Sys.Signal_default
```

Here's a session that shows how it works:

```
$ ocaml
        OCaml version 4.00.1

# #load "unix.cma";;
# #use "rwt.ml";;
exception Timeout
val run_with_timeout : int -> ('a -> 'b) -> 'a -> unit = <fun>
# run_with_timeout 2 Printf.printf "yes\n";;
yes
- : unit = ()
# run_with_timeout 2 (fun () -> while true do () done) ();;
- : unit = ()
#
```

Your code would be something like this:

```
List.iter (run_with_timeout 10 f) data
```

(This code hasn't been thorougly tested but it shows a way that might work.)

**Update**

As the comments have shown, this code isn't suitable if `f x` might throw an exception (or if you're using alarms for some other purpose). I encourage gsg to post his/her improved solution. The edit seems to have been rejected.

Comment: Although I think this is mostly the right approach, you'll get into trouble if `f x` raises. There will be a pending `SIGALRM`, and the handler that raises `Timeout` will still be installed. Also, if there is an existing `SIGALRM` handler it will be silently stomped whether `f x` raises or not. A better way is to use `Sys.signal` to save the old handler, and restore it unconditionally: something like `try ...; finish () with exn -> finish (); exn`, where `finish` restores the old handler and cancels any pending alarm.

Comment: Amen. But maybe a crude solution is OK if things are in a known state (code isn't part of a general-purpose library, etc.).

Comment: @gsg `you'll get into trouble if f x raises` ==> do you mean when `f x` raises exceptions? A part of my `f x` will end up by exceptions, so this code is not suitable?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. You would need to fix the code up a bit if `f x` could raise an exception.

Comment: @gsg This timer is supposed to wrap the whole `f x`, which is complicated (that is why it takes time) and may raise several types of exceptions. I really would like to make it correct, but I am not familiar with Sys or Unix. I am going to update the OP, could you please help with the solution?

Comment: I've queued an edit to Jeffrey's post that should improve exception safety.

Comment: @gsg Do you mean your previous comment or a new edit to Jeffrey's post? I don't see how to implement that `finish`...

Comment: An edit to Jeffrey's post. It might not be visible yet (or it might get knocked back, in which case I'll make a post myself).

Comment: @gsg `I encourage gsg to post his/her improved solution. The edit seems to have been rejected.`